# How to disable dragging on specific element using Vue.Draggable

Tags: vue.js, drag-and-drop, sortablejs

How can I set so that only `.btn-drag` can drag whole  row? I am using https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable

Currently I can drag also with `button#options` which is undesired

```
    <draggable v-model="textElements">
        <transition-group>
            <div class="is-draggable" v-for="element in textElements" :key="element.text">
                <div>
                    {{ element.text }}
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-transparent">Options</button>
                <button class="btn btn-transparent btn-drag">Drag</button>
            </div>
        </transition-group>
    </draggable>
```

In docs they mention that we can place `:move="checkMove"` on `<draggable>` but in function I am not sure how can I check what exactly was dragged? Returning false works correctly for disabling dragging in general

```
methods: {
    checkMove(evt) {
        console.log(evt)
        return false
    }
}
```

Console.log(evt) shows this but I am not sure which property I can use to pinpoint exactly what started a drag https://image.prntscr.com/image/r17zNkxoSWGdVQs_5nR09w.png

Answer (score 18):

The functionality is called "handles".

https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable#features

https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable#options

https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable#options
`handle` option here should help.

Comment: Thank you, this is a solution: <draggable :options="{handle: '.btn-drag'}" ...>

Answer (score 7):

Starting from version 2.19, you can use

```
<draggable handle=".handle">
```

Answer (score 4):

Here the elements with class "item" are only draggable ,
that can specified like this draggable=".item" usign the draggable option inside the draggable tag

```
<draggable v-model="myArray" draggable=".item">
<div v-for="element in myArray" :key="element.id" class="item">
    {{element.name}}
</div>
<button slot="header" @click="addPeople">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a prop in a draggable component.

Example:

```
<draggable :options="{handle: '.drag-only-this'}">
```

For exploring more here is a [All sortable options](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable#all-sortable-options)

Answer (score 1):

can use `:not()` selector for specific element for group of multiple elements

```js
<draggable v-model="myArray" draggable=".item:not(.exclude-this-item)"> 
  <div v-for="element in myArray" :key="element.id" class="item exclude-this-item"> 
    {{element.id}}
  </div>
  <div v-for="element in myArray" :key="element.name" class="item">
    {{element.name}}
  </div>
  <div v-for="element in myArray" :key="element.city" class="item">
    {{element.city}}
  </div>
</draggable>
```

Answer (score 0):

---

the easiest way is to use the prop move

```
<draggable :list="list" :move="checkMove">

checkMove: function(evt){
  return evt.draggedContext.element.name === 'draggable element';
}
```

This checkMove function is called for each element in the list. if it returns true the element will be draggable and vice versa.

Likewise if you want to make the elements non draggable and fixed in its positions, draggable prop can be used. :draggable=".class-name". put the elements that you want to drag under the class .class-name. Rest of the elements will stay put in its place.